# Azure SQL Database - Cannot delete/update registered dacpac unless connected as sql admin

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

This may be a problem with Azure databases, but I'm hoping there is a solution.

On creating an SQL Database in Azure, the server has a SQL Admin account, which is configured, in this case, manually via the Portal when provisioning. This can only be a SQL Authenticated user.

And of course, I have an AAD group/user configured as the AD Admin as well.

I have also set up an automated deployment using SSDT. The problem arises when I attempt to register the DACPAC as part of the deployment, but only after the first deployment if I'm using the AD account to deploy. It tries to update the registered data-tier application but gets an error stating that it already exists. If I deploy with the SQL Authenticated SQL Admin user instead, then it deploys successfully.

For a few reasons, I want to deploy using an AD account, not least of which to be able to create other contained AD users, which a SQL Authenticated user can't do.

Doing some poking about, I'm able to delete the registered dacpac in SSMS if I'm connected as the SQL user, but when I attempt to do so with the AD user I get:

> The current user does not have sufficient permissions on the instance of SQL Server to delete the data-tier application. The user must be the database owner of the database associated with the data-tier application.

I know that the data-tier application info is stored in the virtual master database. e.g.

```
select * [master].[dbo].[sysdac_history_internal] 
select * [master].[dbo].[sysdac_instances_internal]
```

It looks like you need to have db_owner on the master database in order to work with DACs in this way, but the only user that can be db_owner is the SQL authenticated SQL Admin.

So unless I can create a contained AD user that can do this, I don't think I can use dacpac registration, which is a real shame as drift detection is a real seller for the use SSDT.

If anyone knows how to manage this, I'd be very grateful to hear it.

Comment: why do you want to register the dacpac? it isn't a very well used feature, if it is for drift detection then it isn't reliable

Comment: Interesting. Why would you say it's unreliable? I understand that anything outside of the build/model scripts wouldn't be included. Is this what you mean? E.g. Creating users via a post split script.